# Finding nearest string from the list programmatically

Tags: string, comparison, fuzzy-logic

I would like to find the nearest string match from the list given programmatically.
For eg: if I have a list of string as 
List strList = new List(){ "Order" "Employee" "Order Category", "Benefit Calculation" }
And when user gives 'ord'  it should suggest "Order" , if 'emp' is written, it should suggest  "Employee" , if 'bencalc' suggestion should be "Benefit Calculation". 
How can I achieve this programmatically. I have read that 'levenshtein distance' will help. But I feel that will give the distance of insertion/deletion. 
Is there any way for me to get required results.

Regards, 
NAK

Comment: check  [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm)

Comment: Also if you have a specific programming language that you use , you can work with specific methods  (e.g. In javascript  we have [string.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method where it checks if a substring is including in a string ! )